# Abstract class - extended classes and DAO

Tags: java, mysql, dao

I have a abstract class User and 3 classes who extend from this class (Admin, Modurator, Lector).

In my db I have a table User with the data needed (UserName / Password / Security_lvl).

The connection to the database for User I do with DAO.

```
public class MysqlUserDao implements UserDao {
    //
    private static MysqlUserDao instance;

    //
    public static MysqlUserDao getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new MysqlUserDao();
        return instance;
    }
public void create(User user) {
        try {
            c = MySqlDAOFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
            //
            String sql = "insert into user values (?,?,?)";
            //
            prest = c.prepareStatement(sql);
            //
            prest.setString(1, user.getUserName());
            prest.setString(2, user.getPassword());
            prest.setInt(3, user.getRole().returnSecurityLevel());
            //
            prest.executeUpdate();
            //
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JdbcLogging.info("error item" + " :"
                    + e);
        } finally {
            MySqlConnectionFactory.getInstance().closeResultSet(rs);
            MySqlConnectionFactory.getInstance().closeStatement(prest);
            MySqlConnectionFactory.getInstance().closeConnection(c);
        }
    }
```

}

In java depending on the user-type I make the specific Admin, Modurator or Lector objects so I can use their specific methods.

Now the problem I have, is that I need a User for this DAO.  But User is abstract and I do not make any User objects.  I can make three different DAO's for each of the other classes but they would just do the same.  Is there a clean  way to do this ... .

Their maybe is a simple solution but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: I don't see the problem: all the fields you want to store in the database are defined in `User` anyway. Or is it the reverse direction that is causing the problem?

Comment: With create I have to give a User object with it ... but I can't because I don't make User objects but classes extended from User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass Admin, Moderator or Lector instances as parameters to your `create` method. [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) in Java allows that kind of behaviour.

Comment: In fact, this is the very essence of polymorphism.